# JBOSS EAP 6.2.2 Apache Common IO Singer Error for IOUtil.s

Tags: java, apache, jboss, classloader, jboss6.x

I have a web application that uses Apache Common IO version 2.4. When I deploy this application on JBOSS 6.2.2 I am getting following error:

> Failed to define class org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils in Module
>   "deployment.MyApp.war:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils"'s
>   signer information does not match signer information of other classes
>   in the same package

Because of this error, class loader does not load the class and hence getting **NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils** at runtime. I am not sure how to resolve this as this jar is published from Apache foundation.
I did quick check with ***jarsinger*** that comes with JDK, and it says as below.

> jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)

Command I am running:
    jarsigner -verify commons-io-2.4.jar

Did anyone face this issue before? I did see couple of posting stackoverflow, none seems solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when classes belonging to the same package are loaded from different class loaders and the jars files loaded have signatures signed with different certificates or in your case, at least one is signed and one or more others are not.

In JBoss EAP 6.2 commons-io is provided by the server, try remove from your war the `commons-io` jar.

Comment: Thanks..Strangely this happens only on a RHEL box. Not on Windows flavor

Comment: @Chetan JAR files included with JBoss EAP are digitally signed by Red Hat. This does not seem to happen in the Windows installation.